# RANK with built-in condition MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So I have to find the half value of row from this 'price' column and I have to name that half price condition as PromotionPrice, secondly I need to find the PromotionPrice with highest value using rank;

Values

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO brand_item(name,price,shoe_name) 
    VALUES
    ("Nikey",300,"ZingZang"),
    ("Nikey",140,"Limbroz"),
    ("zing",720,"Canterous"),
    ("zing",500,"Heras"),
    ("zing",120,"Kazolvo"),
    ("Lobroso",450,"At"),
    ("Lobroso",150,"Hipsirus");
```

My solution

```
SELECT name,shoe_name,price,
    (price/2) AS PromotionPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            name,shoe_name,price,PromotionPrice,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY price ORDER BY PromotionPrice DESC)
            AS RNK
        FROM interviewqs.brand_item
) tmp
WHERE name = "Lobroso" AND RNK = 1;
```

Expected Output: 225

But my console throws this error; `Unknown column PromotionPrice in the field list`. I know there's a correct syntax to achieve what I desired for but I have done several googling yet no answer.

Comment: first do the rank over price only and use the promo price in the next step .. you cannot rank column which does not exist.. replace the PromotionPrice with price inly after the ORDER BY and remove competely from the inner select

Comment: @Mr.P can you provide the code on answer?

Comment: see the answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first make the rank and filter it later ... you mixed it all up :)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT name 
  , shoe_name 
  , price 
  , price/2 as  promo_price
  , rank() over (partition by name order by (price/2) desc) as highest_price
  FROM brand_item
) as subq
WHERE highest_price = 1
```

Here is the saved DBFiddle demo

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b7bDUDHPTTiA7HfRimToqs/0

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful solution, sometimes I doubt myself of getting into data  position while struggling to think of solution for simple problem..

Comment: no worries.. just practice and it will come :) remember the KISS and DRY principles !! these are vital ..